# How do I discard changes for a file in Git Gui?

Tags: git, git-gui

Often when using Git Gui I would like to reset/checkout a single file or just dismiss a hunk.

Is there a way to do this easily in Git Gui? If not, is there any particular reason that this feature is not available in Git Gui?

Comment: Don't you have `Revert Changes` in the `Commit` menu ?

Comment: Didn't expect it there...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I know this way:

1. The changes must be unstaged
2. Go to **Tools** -> **Add**
3. Choose whatever name you'd like for your command, then in **Command** write
   `git checkout $REVISION -- $FILENAME`
4. Select (left-click) the file you want to checkout, without staging
5. Choose from **Tools** the command you just created

The chosen file will be checked out to `HEAD` revision

Comment: "*the changes must be unchanged*" Did you mean unstaged?

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me (for reverting changes in single file). @StevenM.Vascellaro it works for me when the changes in the file are Unstaged.

Answer (score 51):

I had a same problem. Just found it out: 
CTRL+J or Commit - Revert Changes

Answer (score 41):

1. Select the file from the file list in the left sidebar.
2. In the Menu bar, under Commit, Click "Revert Changes" in the dropdown list.

Alternatively, you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to trigger the same action on Windows.

[image]

Comment: This should b the answer. I was under the impression that that was revert commit. This helped a bunch. Thank You

Comment: This is the best answer how to do it out of the GUI. Thanks!

Comment: Be forewarned this will revert the entire file, not only the selection, and there is no way to undo the change.

Answer (score 0):

Revert Change will work with **untracked files** too, with Git 2.25 and **`git-gui`**.

See [commit 0d2116c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d2116c6441079a5a1091e4cf152fd9d5fa9811b) (04 Jan 2020), [commit 23cbe42](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23cbe427c44645a3ab0449919e55bade5eb264bc) (19 Dec 2019), [commit 1e1ccbf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e1ccbfdd3100a1bb656b11f973381ce4b69decf) (06 Dec 2019), [commit d32e065](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d32e065a9179408db8d29354171258ca183b9443) (11 Dec 2019), and [commit 2763530](https://github.com/git/git/commit/276353004822918d1f45cfc36d0717b878fff600) (05 Dec 2019) by [Pratyush Yadav (`prati0100`)](https://github.com/prati0100).
See [commit 786f4d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/786f4d24057b13184aaff8a5fa2d82a9c0180783) (30 Dec 2019) by [Zoli Szabó (`zoliszabo`)](https://github.com/zoliszabo).
See [commit 39acfa3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39acfa3d224e4a125a3f72ef761ee2cbd24216c2) (07 Dec 2019) by [Kazuhiro Kato (`kkato233`)](https://github.com/kkato233).
See [commit fa38ab6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa38ab68b0ac409f695efcaa23b8bcda84defd41), [commit d9c6469](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9c6469f38737e9c96428a81adf0fc4d97606bb0), [commit 29a9366](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29a9366052d50926bc4426b8540493652cba0766) (01 Dec 2019) by [Jonathan Gilbert (`jpg0`)](https://github.com/jpg0).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fe47c9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe47c9cb5f98e305a15db24b8a9f62151ae65d8d), 08 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-gui`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa38ab68b0ac409f695efcaa23b8bcda84defd41): revert untracked files by deleting them
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Gilbert</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Pratyush Yadav</sup>
>
> Update the `revert_helper` proc to check for untracked files as well as changes, and then handle changes to be reverted and untracked files with independent blocks of code.
>
> Prompt the user independently for untracked files, since the underlying action is fundamentally different (`rm -f`).
>   If after deleting untracked files, the directory containing them becomes empty, then remove the directory as well.
>
> Migrate unlocking of the index out of `_close_updateindex` to a responsibility of the caller, to permit paths that don't directly unlock the index, and refactor the error handling added in [d4e890e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4e890e5de1ea7107d8d1b4134ab0144bbf27b8c) so that callers can make flow control decisions in the event of errors.
>   Update Tcl/Tk dependency from 8.4 to 8.6 in [`git gui`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui).sh.
>
> A new proc `delete_files` takes care of actually deleting the files in batches, using the Tcler's Wiki recommended approach for keeping the UI responsive.
>
> Since the `checkout_index` and `delete_files` calls are both asynchronous and could potentially complete in any order, a "chord" is used to coordinate unlocking the index and returning the UI to a usable state only after both operations are complete. The `SimpleChord` class, based on TclOO (Tcl/Tk 8.6), is added in this commit.

Answer (score -2):

Select the file you want to reset from the "Unstaged changes window".
Then click Menù - Branch - Reset -

You will have the file before the changes you did as the last commit.

Comment: Is worth mentioning that this will revert ALL uncommitted changes, not just an specific file.

Comment: If a user wants to only revert one file, this is going to mess them up!